# Unable to update using Retrofit from the ID i declared into it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

Here is my update button functions

```
val task = UpdateTask(
            taskName, taskDesc, category, dueDate, assignee, pointEarned
        )
        if (getData != null) {
            val id2 = getData.taskId
            Log.e("yes", "yes " + id2)
            GroomedKidzApi.retrofitService.updateTask(id2, makeGSONRequestBody(task))
                .enqueue(object : Callback<TasksItem?> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<TasksItem?>,
                        response: Response<TasksItem?>
                    ) {
                        val responseBody = response.body()
                        if (responseBody != null) {
                            Log.e("qqq", "yes " + responseBody)
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@UpdateTaskActivity,
                                "Update Successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<TasksItem?>, t: Throwable) {
                        Log.e("FAIL", "FAIL " + id2)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@UpdateTaskActivity,
                            "Update Unsuccessfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                })
        }
```

I have retrieve the specific ID and put into id2. Is this how i update my task ID by writing it?

```
updateTask(id2, makeGSONRequestBody(task))
```

This will be my APIinterface

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @PUT("api/Tasks/{id}")
    fun updateTask(@Path("id") id: Int, @Body requestBody: RequestBody): Call<TasksItem>
```

When i press update button, im able to get the log message with correct id2, but API is not even call, onFailure message is also not shown too